# Передача параметров через ссылку в Java

Tags: java, ссылки

Решал задачи абрамяна на Java. До решал до proc, и вот теперь никак не могу решить proc1. Даны два вещественных числа, нужно описать процедуру PowerA3(a,b), которая возводит число а в третью степень присваивает это значение переменной b, а переменная b должна передаваться в процедуру как ссылка. Проблема: в java нет ссылок и указателей. Реализовал решение с помощью класса, то есть передал объекты в параметрах, но это решение мне не так уж и нравится. Как можно решить задачу по другому?

Comment: Никак, передачи по ссылке в джаве на самом деле нет (есть только передачи ссылки как обычного аргумента). С учетом того, что у вас возвращается одно значение, несколько странно не возвращать его через привычный return.

Comment: Вряд ли эту задачу можно решить как-то по-другому. А вообще, было бы неплохо увидеть задание в оригинале.

Comment: Если учесть что (как минимум изначально) Абрамян ничего кроме паскакаля не знал, и в задачнике для java слово pascal тупо заменено на java и всё, то этот задачник можно использовать только сами догадайтесь как. Ищите задачники именно для изучаемого предмета, а не халтурные переделки из других.

Comment: @post_zeew В оригинале это задача для паскаля. Изучающему java не надо на неё смотреть.

Comment: @Sergey, Я не знаю, кто такой Абрамян, но слово `процедура` меня навела на определенные мысли.

Comment: Большое спасибо)) Не мог бы кто-нибудь из вас порекомендовать хороший задачник для тренировки и укрепления знаний Java?